# How to remove box-shadow hover from div while hovering over nested div?

Tags: css

I have circles nested within and centered ontop of each other in the html. I want to remove the boxshadow hover of the largest circle when I hover over the second largest. When I hover over the next consecutive circles they keep the hover on from the previous circles. I tried to make that hover cancel out using this boxshadow: none but to no avail.
 I posted my html and css codes

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

body, header {
    width: 760px;
    height: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

.container {
    width: 760px;
    height: 760px;
    }   

.circle1 {
    background-image: url("images/circle4.svg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 1;
    }   

.circle2 {
    background-image: url("images/circle3.svg");
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 94px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
    }

.circle3 {
    background-image: url("images/circle2.svg");
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 112px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
    }

.circle4 {
    background-image: url("images/circle1.svg");
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 104px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
    }



.circle1:hover .circle2{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

.circle2:hover .circle3{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 117px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

.circle3:hover .circle4{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

.circle2:hover .circle1{
    box-shadow: none;
}

.circle3:hover .circle2{
    box-shadow: none;
}

.circle4:hover .circle3{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>

    <title>
        My Website!
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle.css" />

</head>

<body>


    <header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="circle1">
                <div class="circle2">
                    <div class="circle3">
                        <div class="circle4">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would probably need JS as there is no CSS parent selector.

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of your code in jsfiddle.net to make it easier to test?

Comment: As @Paulie_D said there is no way to select parents in CSS. You could put the circle divs as siblings and position them on top of each other, then apply an inset box-shadow to the circe itself.